# Share ethernet connected printer with CUPS to Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, ethernet, printing

I'm searching and trying for days now to get a LAN-Network Printer (Kyocera) working. Here is what I want:

[Printer] - [eth0| RPi/CUPS | wlan0 ] - [Wifi]

Here is what I have:

- ip_forward enabled
- CUPS installed
- my interfaces file

`auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

- I tried to give eth0 an ip from the Wifi (192.168.0.xxx) - not
  working
- I tried bridging - not working
- I tried many other things to, but every solution I found via google differs a little bit from what I want/need!

I think I'm only a few steps away from the solution. But I can't find any good tutorial. It's all about sharing a USB-Printer...